# Tikz: How to better distinguish between arrows to one coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In my tikz pictures there are several arrows pointing on the same coordinate. The arrows heads look very ugly.  I want to see every arrow head separately. How can I improve my picture?

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\linewidth/10cm]
% Help Lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-2.95) grid (4.95,3.95);
% Ellipse
\draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
\draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
% Text
\draw (-2.5,2) node (a) {-4};
\draw (-2.5,1) node (b) {-1,5};
\draw (-2.5,0) node (c) {0};
\draw (-2.5,-1) node (d) {3};
\draw (-2.5,-2) node (e) {7,25};
\draw (2.5,0) node (f) {3};
% Arrow
\draw[thick,->] (a) -- (f);
\draw[thick,->] (b) -- (f);
\draw[thick,->] (c) -- (f);
\draw[thick,->] (d) -- (f);
\draw[thick,->] (e) -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three different suggestions. i) shortening arrows, ii) changing endpoint, iii) curved arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}    

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\linewidth/10cm,
  myArrow/.style={thick,->,shorten >=10pt}]
% Help Lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-2.95) grid (4.95,3.95);
% Ellipse
\draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
\draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
% Text
\draw (-2.5,2) node (a) {-4};
\draw (-2.5,1) node (b) {-1,5};
\draw (-2.5,0) node (c) {0};
\draw (-2.5,-1) node (d) {3};
\draw (-2.5,-2) node (e) {7,25};
\draw (2.5,0) node (f) {3};
% Arrow
\draw[myArrow] (a) -- (f);
\draw[myArrow] (b) -- (f);
\draw[myArrow] (c) -- (f);
\draw[myArrow] (d) -- (f);
\draw[myArrow] (e) -- (f);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\linewidth/10cm,
  myArrow/.style={thick,->}]
% Help Lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-2.95) grid (4.95,3.95);
% Ellipse
\draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
\draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
% Text
\draw (-2.5,2) node (a) {-4};
\draw (-2.5,1) node (b) {-1,5};
\draw (-2.5,0) node (c) {0};
\draw (-2.5,-1) node (d) {3};
\draw (-2.5,-2) node (e) {7,25};
\draw (2.5,0) node (f) {3};
% Arrow
\draw[myArrow] (a) -- ([yshift=5pt]f.west);
\draw[myArrow] (b) -- ([yshift=2.4pt]f.west);
\draw[myArrow] (c) -- (f.west);
\draw[myArrow] (d) -- ([yshift=-2.5pt]f.west);
\draw[myArrow] (e) -- ([yshift=-5pt]f.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  scale=\linewidth/10cm,
  myArrow/.style={thick,->}]
% Help Lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-2.95) grid (4.95,3.95);
% Ellipse
\draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
\draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
% Text
\draw (-2.5,2) node (a) {-4};
\draw (-2.5,1) node (b) {-1,5};
\draw (-2.5,0) node (c) {0};
\draw (-2.5,-1) node (d) {3};
\draw (-2.5,-2) node (e) {7,25};
\draw (2.5,0) node (f) {3};
% Arrow
\draw[myArrow] (a) to[out=0,in=125] (f);
\draw[myArrow] (b) to[out=0,in=150] (f);
\draw[myArrow] (c) -- (f);
\draw[myArrow] (d) to[out=0,in=210] (f);
\draw[myArrow] (e) to[out=0,in=245] (f);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: "ii) changing endpoint" works very well for me. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is easy with a simple calculation. To perform it, we need the `calc` library, and we'll also make use of the anchor system to decide where the arrow ends.

Your arrows are ordered and all go to the same node, therefore we can simplify that with a `\foreach` first, then use it to calculate end coordinates. If you don't understand something, feel free to comment.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}%[scale=\linewidth/10cm]
% Help Lines
\draw[step=1,help lines,black!20] (-4.95,-2.95) grid (4.95,3.95);
% Ellipse
\draw[thick] (-2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
\draw[thick] (2.5,0) ellipse [x radius=1.75, y radius=3];
% Text
\node (a) at (-2.5,2)  {-4};
\node (b) at (-2.5,1)  {-1,5};
\node (c) at (-2.5,0)  {0};
\node (d) at (-2.5,-1) {3};
\node (e) at (-2.5,-2) {7,25};
\node (f) at (2.5,0)   {3};

\foreach \lett [
    count=\x starting from 0, 
    evaluate=\x as \xx using ((\x*25)/100),
    ] in {a,b,c,d,e}{
    \draw[thick,->] (\lett) -- ($(f.north west)!\xx!(f.south west)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: I didn't downvote.

Comment: @Sr.Shneider Oh no worries. I was more interested in the why than the who. I was just surprised, that's all. :D